# Add a like in Ultimate Member directory and Profile

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ultimate-member

I am using Ultimate Member in my WP site. I would like to show in member directory an icon in the shape of an heart that an user can click to like another user in member directory or in the profile and the user that receive that, can see who sent him/her the like in a tab of the profile that i have already prepared, and visit their profile clicking on their name. I found a perfect plugin that make all this and is called LIKEBTN, but the free version can show only 1 icon for page, then can't go in the directory and the position of the btn in the profile is almost hidden because covered from the gear of the option. So because i can't  afford to buy the full version, i come to the conclusion to make it from scratch, but i need a little help and idea on how to do it. A little code of example that then i can expand and adapt would be great. Thank You in advance for your kind advices.

Answer (score 1):

[image: example]

You can take a table say **favorites** and store the ids of the preferred users

> you have to validate the user_id ( current user ) should not be preferred user id
> when a user clicks like - there will be an entry, and when "un-like" the record should be removed :: if  present.

May be this can help

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will try to apply your suggestion. :)